# Increasing sequence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence defined as follows

$$a_0 = 0$$
$$a_1=\dfrac 12$$
$$a_{n+2}=\dfrac 13(1+a_{n+1}+a_n^3)$$

It is asked to prove that $(a_n)$ is increasing.

I tried strong induction but in vain.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you see that if $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and $a_n > a_{n-1}$, then $a_{n+2} > a_{n+1}$ ? This lets you do strong induction quite easily (once you've checked it for the first $3$ values $a_0, a_1, a_2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- base case: $n=0 \implies a_{2}=\dfrac 13(1+a_{1}+a_0^3)=\frac12\ge a_1$
- induction step: assuming true for any $n=0$ to $k$ that $a_{n+2}\ge a_{n+1}$ we need to prove that $a_{n+3}=\dfrac 13(1+a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}^3)\ge a_{n+2}$

then we have

$$a_{n+3}=\dfrac 13(1+a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}^3)\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}{\ge}\dfrac 13(1+a_{n+1}+a_{n}^3)=a_{n+2}$$